# Ruby on Rails 3 can't open port in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, websocket

I have server (WHM, ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.3, centOS, passenger) and I just deploy my RoR app (it works on local computer) but I get strange behavior in production mode.

I'm using web_socket.rb file from

> http://gimite.net/en/

and when I want to start web socket server with:

```
Thread.start {  
 @sockets = []
      Thread.abort_on_exception = true
      server = WebSocketServer.new( :accepted_domains => "*", :port => session[:port])
      logger.debug "Server is running at port %d" % server.port   



  server.run() do |ws|


    puts("Connection accepted")
    puts("Path: #{ws.path}, Origin: #{ws.origin}")

    if ws.path == "/"
      ws.handshake()
      @sockets << ws
      while data = ws.receive()

        printf("Received: %p\n", data)

          @sockets.each {|s| s.send(data)}

        printf("Sent: %p\n", data)
      end
    else
      ws.handshake("404 Not Found")
    end
    puts("Connection closed")
  end
  }
end
```

I don't get new Thread running. When I start without "Thread.start" I get this error:

```
Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT (Address family not supported by protocol - socket(2)):
  lib/web_socket.rb:314:in `initialize'
  lib/web_socket.rb:314:in `open'
  lib/web_socket.rb:314:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/access_controller.rb:53:in `new'
  app/controllers/access_controller.rb:53:in `socket'
  app/controllers/access_controller.rb:29:in `attempt_login'
```

I trying to figure out what is the problem, but I'm stuck :|

How do I know that port is maybe problem?

Because in web_socket.rb, line 314 is:

```
if params[:host]
        @tcp_server = TCPServer.open(params[:host], @port)
      else
        @tcp_server = TCPServer.open(@port)
      end
```

Comment: I tried to turn off Firewall on my server, but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must to use background processes instead of Threads

Comment: Can you expand on this answer?  I'm having the same issue too

Answer (score 0):

May be your server has IPV6 for localhost

user 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts

it solved my problem